# Error React-natvie build configuration on Windows

Tags: react-native

According to the information obtained from here(https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/getting-started.html#content), I was going to step on the stage.

But I was faced with a problem.
The problem arose when the input as shown below.

```
react-native init ReactLog
```

In the console window, the following error messages are shown.

```
This will walk you through creating a new React Native project in F:\Android\Rea
ctLog
Installing react-native package from npm...

npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mo
dules\which\which.js:78:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mo
dules\which\which.js:82:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modul
es\which\which.js:93:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  facebook/react#b4e74e3 resetting remote C:\Users\Reddol\A
ppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-facebook-react-git-b4e74e3-
c92d21d2e268ee43029cdd9b3cd02392 because of error: { [Error: not found: git] cod
e: 'ENOGIT' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Reddol\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-rem
otes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/facebook/react.git C:\Users\Reddol\App
Data\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-facebook-react-git-b4e74e3-c9
2d21d2e268ee43029cdd9b3cd02392: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Reddol\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-rem
otes\_templates --mirror git://github.com/facebook/react.git C:\Users\Reddol\App
Data\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-facebook-react-git-b4e74e3-c9
2d21d2e268ee43029cdd9b3cd02392: undefined
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mo
dules\which\which.js:78:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mo
dules\which\which.js:82:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modul
es\which\which.js:93:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  facebook/react#b4e74e3 resetting remote C:\Users\Reddol\A
ppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-facebook-react-git-b4
e74e3-7ac9f0e64c0248b5a8c1d179336b39d8 because of error: { [Error: not found: gi
t] code: 'ENOGIT' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Reddol\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-rem
otes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/facebook/react.git C:\Users\Reddol\A
ppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-facebook-react-git-b4
e74e3-7ac9f0e64c0248b5a8c1d179336b39d8: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Reddol\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-rem
otes\_templates --mirror https://github.com/facebook/react.git C:\Users\Reddol\A
ppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-https-github-com-facebook-react-git-b4
e74e3-7ac9f0e64c0248b5a8c1d179336b39d8: undefined
npm WARN addRemoteGit Error: not found: git
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at F (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mo
dules\which\which.js:78:19)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at E (C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_mo
dules\which\which.js:82:29)
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modul
es\which\which.js:93:16
npm WARN addRemoteGit     at FSReqWrap.oncomplete (fs.js:82:15)
npm WARN addRemoteGit  facebook/react#b4e74e3 resetting remote C:\Users\Reddol\A
ppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-facebook-react-git-b4e74e3-
a74af502d8e5579c42e0f6b0488923ce because of error: { [Error: not found: git] cod
e: 'ENOGIT' }
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Reddol\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-rem
otes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:facebook/react.git C:\Users\Reddol\AppDa
ta\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-facebook-react-git-b4e74e3-a74a
f502d8e5579c42e0f6b0488923ce: undefined
npm ERR! git clone --template=C:\Users\Reddol\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-rem
otes\_templates --mirror git@github.com:facebook/react.git C:\Users\Reddol\AppDa
ta\Roaming\npm-cache\_git-remotes\git-github-com-facebook-react-git-b4e74e3-a74a
f502d8e5579c42e0f6b0488923ce: undefined
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "--save" "react-native"
npm ERR! node v5.1.0
npm ERR! npm  v3.3.12
npm ERR! code ENOGIT

npm ERR! not found: git
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed using git.
npm ERR! This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
npm ERR! Please check if you have git installed and in your PATH.

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     F:\Android\ReactLog\npm-debug.log

`npm install --save react-native` failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Install git tools for windows(http://git-scm.com/download/win) and make sure the git.exe is added the PATH environment variable.